# DataGrip SSL error: Tag mismatch! javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, jetbrains-ide, datagrip

I got this error

`[08006] SSL error: Tag mismatch! javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch!.`

after PostgreSQL has been upgraded to version 12.

I also upgraded JDBC driver to latest version, but it didn't help.

I googled it but I found only some unrelated Java code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. There is an option "sslmode" in connection properties/advanced tab. It must be set to "allow". Then everything will work.

Comment: 'allow' means it does ssl only if the server insists.  So you have probably fixed the problem just be not using ssl at all.

Comment: @jjanes I guess so. But I need only a fix, SSL doesn't matter for me at this moment.